# How to call a sed command in a python script?

Tags: python, linux, unix

Through python script, I am trying to sed command that through `subprocess.call()` as it in the script.

```
file = "a.xml"
updateData= "(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=abc)(PORT=1234)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=centraldb)))"
subprocess.call(["sed", "-i", 's#<DB_CONNECT_STRING>.*</DB_CONNECT_STRING>#<DB_CONNECT_STRING>updateData</DB_CONNECT_STRING>#', file])
```

When I run the command in the shell script or command, it runs fine, but in python I get a result saying "No input file". Any idea how to fix that error?

`a.xml` looks something like this.

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?> 
<!DOCTYPE properties SYSTEM "java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd"> 

<properties> <!-- Database server details --> 
    <DB_CONNECT_STRING>(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=abc)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=cdb)))</DB_CONNECT_STRING> 
</properties>
```

Comment: That's weird. I am getting a 0 as the output, instead of `No Input File`. Can you post the `a.xml` file, and share it here? Through pastebin or something?

Comment: Where's the "complete and verifiable example"? Voted to close.

Comment: I am running the same code from the question, and it is working fine. Have a look [here](https://onlinegdb.com/SkChP6o0Q) for the same code. Also, what should be the expected output (how a.xml should look after running the program)? My output file looks like `aModified.xml` in the above link.

Comment: Are you running Python on a different host than where you are trying this interactively? The `-i` option requires an option on some platforms (notably *BSD / MacOS) but not on others.

Answer (score 0):

You really don't need or want to use an external subprocess for this.

```
import fileinput

updateData = "(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=abc)(PORT=1234)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=centraldb)))"

for line in fileinput.input('a.xml', inplace=True):
    try:
        prefix, tail = line.split('<DB_CONNECT_STRING>', 1)
        _, suffix = tail.split('</DB_CONNECT_STRING>', 1)
        line = prefix + '<DB_CONNECT_STRING>' + updateData + '</DB_CONNECT_STRING>' + suffix
    except ValueError:
        # <DB_CONNECT_STRING> or close tag not found -- don't replace
        pass
    print(line)
```

For the record, `updateData` inside quotes does not magically change into the value of the variable `updateData`  so that was another problem with your attempt.

The ad-hoc XML processing is still a major wart; a proper solution would use an XML parser and perhaps XSLT to update the file. (On the other hand, if you know for a fact that the line will never contain anything outside the start and end tags, you can simplify the above script somewhat. On the third hand, the ad-hoc s-expressions inside the XML tags looks like you really want to rethink the configuration file format more thoroughly if you have any control at all over this.)